# WPF TextBox.Focus() annoyance

Tags: wpf, textbox, focus

I'm very new to .Net and WPF and have a problem. The code is a snippet. I have `TextBox`es to enter dates. I check on correct input using `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events.

```
<TextBox Name="sdDay" Width="40" Text="Day" GotFocus="DateDay_GotFocus" LostFocus="DateDay_LostFocus" Padding="5,5,5,5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="True"/>
<TextBox Name="sdMonth" Width="50" Text="Month" GotFocus="DateMonth_GotFocus" LostFocus="DateMonth_LostFocus" Padding="5,5,5,5" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="True"/>
<TextBox Name="sdYear" Width="50" Text="Year" GotFocus="DateYear_GotFocus" LostFocus="DateYear_LostFocus" Padding="5,5,5,5" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Focusable="True"/>
```

And the code:

```
private void DateDay_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text == "Day")
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = string.Empty;
    }

private void DateDay_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text == string.Empty)
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = "Day";
        else
            CheckForCorrectDateDay((TextBox)sender);
    }

private void CheckForCorrectDateDay(TextBox b)
    {
        int day = 0;

        try
        {
            day = int.Parse(b.Text);

            if (day < 0 || day > 31)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a correct day.");
                b.Text = string.Empty;
                b.Focus();
            }
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number.", "Incorrect Input", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Warning);
            b.Text = string.Empty;
            b.Focus();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Now what I want it to do is check for correct input, and if that fails, set the focus back to whatever `TextBox` had an incorrect entry.

It doesn't work though. After I enter a number outside the range (or letter), the `MessageBox` will show but the focus shifts to the next TextBox which is for entering the month.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your technique for validation here is, to be frank, very poor. That said, I believe the problem is just that WPF is handling the tab after you've set focus, so it is setting focus back to the next item in the focus order.

A simple workaround would be to dispatch a separate message that is processed after the current message:

```
if (day < 0 || day > 31)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please enter a correct day.");
    b.Text = string.Empty;

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ThreadStart)delegate
    {
        b.Focus();
    });
}
```

Doing this ensures that WPF completely processes the `LostFocus` event handler before it processes the separate message to set focus on the erroneous control.

In terms of how you could tackle this problem in a much nicer way, you could:

1. Define a view model with properties for Day, Month, and Year (prerequisite: read up on the MVVM pattern)
2. Implement `IDataErrorInfo` on the view model
3. Bind the `TextBox`es in the UI to the corresponding properties on the view model (prerequisite: read up on WPF data binding)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand your explanation of the problem but not exactly what the solution does. Like I said, I'm very new to .Net.

And I wouldn't mind some tips on better validation techniques.

Comment: Sure thing. Added some more detail to my post.

Comment: I'd like to echo Kent's comment - forcing the focus back is a sure way to make your users angry.

Comment: 1 up for kent, don't try to treat all those events, better use some validation interface: implement IDataErrorInfo or use ValidationRules to validate input.

Comment: U r one of the best :) Wonderful answer :)